# Is it possible to change the @keyframes with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently playing around with CSS3 animations and would like to see what the possibilities are.

So I currently have an infinite animation cycle that works perfectly but I was wondering if it is possible to change the @keyframes when a link is selected.

So what I was thinking about:

-There is a animation running

-There are 3 links

-I have a set of 3 @keyframes

-When a link is selected the @keyframes change to another set of @keyframes

-This to be done without refreshing the page.

Maybe it is a very foolish and stupid question but as I was saying I'm trying to find out what the possibilities are.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily have a CSS class which animates using keyframes 1, then have another class that uses keyframes 2.

You could then use JavaScript / jQuery to add and remove the different classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know but I would like to do it with pure CSS. Just like you could manipulate the css with :target. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target